# InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in I18N.Common.Manager on unity build

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I've been using the system.data.sqlclient library for a while now to access my sql server database in my game. I tested things out on the editor and it seemed fine but when I made the desktop build I got this error [image: NotSupportedException: Encoding 1252 data could not be found].

One thing I've noticed is that the exception occured when I'm simply connecting to the database as I made it connect to the database on Start(). Here is my code for it

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connectString.DataSource = "SampleSource";
connectString.InitialCatalog = "TestSource";
connectString.IntegratedSecurity = true;

SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectString.ConnectionString);

try {
    sqlConn.Open();
    Debug.Log("Game Server connected to database successfully");
} catch (SqlException e) {
    Debug.Log(e);
}
```

I've looked around and eventually saw this solution https://discussions.unity.com/t/invalid-il-code-in-build/238204 where all I need to do is copy and paste I18N.dll and I18N.West.dll somewhere in my assets folder but now I'm getting this error [image: InvalidProgramException].

I also tried copying the aforementioned dlls from unityaot-win32 folder but it still doesn't work. I also tried putting an xml file that contained this code but to no avail.

```
<linker>
<assembly fullname="I18N" preserve="all"/>
<assembly fullname="I18N.West" preserve="all"/>
<assembly fullname="GeometryGymIFC" preserve="all"/>
</linker>
```

I think the main issue really stems from the System.data.sqlclient but idk how to fix it.

Comment: you said "somewhere in my asset folder".. it matters where, it should be in the correct place.  What folder did you put the DLLs in?

Comment: I created a "Plugins" folder in my assets and put them there, I think I saw someone do this so I just followed it.

Comment: this would be right, so, what  .net compatibility are you using in your build? and did you get the i18n from the same folder as the data under unity install?

Comment: I'm using .net framework since it's the only one that works with system.data.sqlclient. As for the I18N, I got it from here: Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.15f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\unity and I tried the other folders on mono as well like unityjit and unityaot

Comment: have you tried lib\mono\4.7.2 ?

Comment: trying it right now and I'm already getting this issue: Loading assembly failed: "Assets/Plugins/I18N.West.dll" reason: File does not contain a valid CIL image

Comment: did you get it from the same folder?

Comment: I got it fixed now, I tried just copying all the I18N dlls from a folder, pasting them on the plugins folder, see if it works and if not try a different one. I don't even know what folder worked but it did so I'll keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, hope you have a great day

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the link does work, just try copying the six I18N dlls from different folders in Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.15f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\ and paste them in the "Plugins" folder and then see which one of the folders work. Idk what folder worked for me eveuntually as I was mindlessly doing it out of exhaustion.

[image]

Comment: to be fair unity seem to give us way too many options and no explaination on why which would be right or not..